# Are there any proofs and formula to count all simple labeled, connected isomorphic and non isomorphic connected simple graphs separately?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

The number of labeled graphs with n vertices are $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$. The
number of connected labeled graphs with n vertices follows the following recurrence,
$C_{n} = 2^{\binom{n}{2}} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k} 2^{\binom{n-2}{2}} C_{k}$

But this gives all isomorphic and non isomorphic simple labeled connected graphs. How can I get the proofs and formula for all isomorphic and non isomorphic labeled simple connected graphs separately?

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to get such information.

The number of non-isomorphic labelled connected simple graphs on $n$ vertices is the same as the number of unlabelled connected simple graphs on $n$ vertices; this is [OEIS A$001349$](http://oeis.org/A001349). The OEIS entry gives no recurrence, closed form, or generating function, and a quick look at the list of references suggests that the values that are known have been determined by algorithmic enumeration using computers.

Comment: That means its an open problem..... no formula is present in this case. As the algorithmic enumeration is not sufficient rather than a concrete proof.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott, sir how can you conclude that the number of non-isomorphic labelled connected simple graphs on n vertices is the same as the number of unlabelled connected simple graphs on n vertices? I am not found any basis. And if it true, then what is the strategy to find number of unlabelled connected simple graphs on n vertices. [note: Is it derives from orbit stabilizer lemma + Burnside lemma ??] Thnaks

Comment: @Subhajit: When you say that two labelled graphs are isomorphic, you could mean either of two things: (1) they are identical, or (2) they are identical as unlabelled graphs but are (possibly) labelled differently. If you mean (1), it makes no sense to distinguish the isomorphic and non-isomorphic cases, so I assume that you mean (2). And in that case two labelled graphs are isomorphic iff they have the same underlying unlabelled graph: they differ only in how that graph is labelled.

Comment: @Brain M.Scott, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Brain M.Scot. sir, then one more question is arise. How many ways that a labeled graph can be labeled? I mean if a connected graph with 3 vertices is labeled in 6 ways like (123,132,213,231,312,321), hence $n!$ required for n vertices.

Comment: @Subhajit: If you mean the number of *distinguishable* ways to label a graph, the answer is that it depends on the graph. Thd complete graph $K_n$ has only one distinguishable labelling with labels $1,\dots,n$, but an $n$-cycle has $(n-1)!$.